# How to configure client-maven-plugin for Maven?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, gluon-mobile

I am trying to transform the build.gradle, IntelliJ created when I created Project "Gluon Mobile - Multiple Views", into an .pom, because I get along better with Maven.

Information: 
OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Home
Systemtype: 64-bit
IDE: IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2019.3.3

I set my JDK to 11, therethrough the plugin jfxmobile was incompatible.

My .pom actually

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.mats</groupId>
    <artifactId>PromptTextFill</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>PromptTextFill</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>client-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.12</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>android</target>
                    <mainClass>mats.app.test.PromptTextFill</mainClass>
                    <graalvmHome>C:/Program Files/Java/graalvm_jdk11_20.0.0</graalvmHome>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>gluon-releases</id>
            <url>http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

I even copied the pom from the [Gluon Documentation](https://docs.gluonhq.com/client/) and changed it to my fits, but still.. it throws an error running a maven task

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:client-maven-plugin:0.1.12:compile (default-cli) on project PromptTextFill: Error: Cannot run program "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc" (in directory "C:\Users\mats2\Desktop\PromptTextFill\target\client\aarch64-l
inux\gvm\PromptTextFill"): CreateProcess error=2, System can't find file
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:client-maven-plugin:0.1.12:compile (default-cli) on project PromptTextFill: Error
```

Greetings and keep a cool head :))
MatsG23

Comment: You didn't follow my advice... You are mixing everything, and that won't work. `jfxmobile` plugin is for Java 1.8, that won't work with the `javafx-gradle-plugin`, for Java 11+. And Charm 6.0.3, for Java 11+, is intended to work with the `client-maven-plugin`. Start here: https://github.com/gluonhq/client-samples

Comment: ok i tried this maven thing, but.....  `Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:client-maven-plugin:0.1.17:package (default-cli) on project PromptTextFill: Error
`  that says nothing (just "error"), but i really followed your instruction "how to build with maven" at link exactly

Comment: and when I try to add charm 6.0.3 as dependency, it says `Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.gluonhq:charm-glisten:jar:6.0.3` @JoséPereda

Comment: Please, read the [README](https://github.com/gluonhq/client-samples/blob/master/README.md), and related [documentation](https://docs.gluonhq.com/client)

Comment: @JoséPereda the plugin code in documentation is the same as mine

Comment: We can’t debug your problem over comments. At least rework your question and post what you have tried with enough details like OS, Java version and alike

Comment: @JoséPereda ok, yes Stack Overflow already tells me "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" :D